# how to check if any of the button in each row is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Suppose there is 3 row,thus there is 3 different name of radio button and each of them have another 5 radio button with different value.

Code:

```
$i = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td width="19"><?php echo $i ?></td>
        <td colspan="4"> <?php echo $row["question"] ?></td>
        <?php

        echo '<td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="1" Name="point' . $i . '" value="1"  />1</td>';
        echo '<td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="2" Name="point' . $i . '" value="2"  />2</td>';
        echo '<td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="3" Name="point' . $i . '" value="3"  />3</td>';
        echo '<td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="4" Name="point' . $i . '" value="4"  />4</td>';
        echo '<td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="5" Name="point' . $i . '" value="5"  />5</td>';
        ?>
        <br />
        </tr>
    <?php 
    $i++;}
```

Comment: if(!document.txtfrm.point1.checked)

Comment: ive try this code yet...it detect all the button of that name that have not been click

Comment: Your question and related code should be posted above,not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking some like this:

```
  $("button").click(function() {
    var $rows = $("table tr");
    var $checked = $rows.find("input:checked");
    var remaining = $rows.length - $checked.length;
    if(remaining > 0)
      alert("answer all the questions: " + remaining + " remaining")
    else
      alert("sending info")
  });
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var $rows = $("table tr");
    var $checked = $rows.find("input:checked");
    var remaining = $rows.length - $checked.length;
    if(remaining > 0)
      alert("answer all the questions: " + remaining + " remaining")
    else
      alert("sending info")
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
 <td width="19">1</td>
 <td colspan="4"> question</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="1" Name="point1" value="1"  />1</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="2" Name="point1" value="2"  />2</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="3" Name="point1" value="3"  />3</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="4" Name="point1" value="4"  />4</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="5" Name="point1" value="5"  />5</td>
 <br />
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td width="19">2</td>
 <td colspan="4"> question</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="1" Name="point2" value="1"  />1</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="2" Name="point2" value="2"  />2</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="3" Name="point2" value="3"  />3</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="4" Name="point2" value="4"  />4</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="5" Name="point2" value="5"  />5</td>
 <br />
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td width="19">3</td>
 <td colspan="4"> question</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="1" Name="point3" value="1"  />1</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="2" Name="point3" value="2"  />2</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="3" Name="point3" value="3"  />3</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="4" Name="point3" value="4"  />4</td>
 <td width="42"><Input type="Radio" id="5" Name="point3" value="5"  />5</td>
 <br />
  </tr>
</table>
<button>submit</button>
```

Comment: $("button").click(function() {
    var $rows = $("table tr"); // total rows
    var $checked = $rows.find("input:checked"); // get checked radios
    var completed = $rows.length < $checked.length; // calculate difference

    if(completed)
      alert("answer all the questions")
    else
      alert("sending info")
  });

Comment: yes it does have to be inside of `<script>`, btw I just edited my answer, wasn't working properly

Comment: its not work as i put it on <script>..newbie fault i guess

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
 $("button").click(function() {
   var $rows = $("table tr");
   var $checked = $rows.find("input:checked");
   var remaining = $rows.length - $checked.length;
   if(remaining > 0)
     alert("answer all the questions: " + remaining + " remaining")
       else
     alert("sending info")
  });
})
```

Comment: does it valid as i put it like this.?

Comment: just use `<script>` instead of `<script language="javascript">`

Comment: ive try...idk but it wont executed the code within <script>